# TypeScritp Type a generic structure in a JSON

Tags: json, typescript, generics

I have a JSON like this:

```
{ users: {
  "username": {"name": "text","last_name": "other text"},
  "username2": {"name": "text","last_name": "other text"},
  "username3": {"name": "text","last_name": "other text"}
  ...
}
```

And I want to type this as generic, something like this:

```
  type UserInfo = {name:string, last_name:string}

 type user<T> = {
   T: UserInfo
} 
 type users = {
   users: user<string>
 }
```

I'm trying to use the generic of user as the key for the object, so I don't have to define a key for username, username2, etc and to make it extensible to "n" username.
but it is not working

Comment: This JSON resides in a variable or it is acquired at runtime?

Comment: Boogie, can u please explain your goal clearly

Comment: Is this fit your need? [URL](http://shorturl.at/bpuy0)

Comment: Also check [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAVhcMC8MDeAoGMCuECmAThAFzpbYwBEeRYAhgLb5VlrUPOvVT4AeUKgBpqAG3rQA+pxZkqIKAAsiMXgKowAvkIrYaBQjIBM3dlRncqawSKripFuQuWFV-QVp2VqtQ03wAzKYc-pbWwmISUNKhTkoq4VoUmhgpGFAAngAO+DAAqgYAkmAAZiAo6DAyZNCEAJZgAOYi9tHVMLUNjUkYAPS9MABuRBB1SACMMADuLrkISHUQMADWYCBTYDD0sKCMWXWiuVB1zOnZub4VmNgA2gDSMA0r+BkgJarnb-CIYAC6ZAUiMUyqkMH0BjgwKt1pt5mAzjlcAYjFcKPdHpsAAa+GQAEjQYBwjAARkRNJj-vkiqUQKDMojfEtUNckSMyL5QRhQJBYFl2cirpoANxgoA) out :)

Comment: My last link does not work above. Here is another one: [URL](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgSQHYDMD2UC8UDeUqAhgLYQBccwiAlqgOYA0UANsdQPonlU33MoAXwCwAKHGhIUAK4JEcADwAVKBAAewCKgAmcKNTqNcB-owB8J-OKiz5cCgRu2oAbQDWEEFHpRlAXUd4JDQsZyEmcVEJMQBjTFRqKAArOASAEWJgYkc5JH08azFbPIVHIpcoACJSnggq8qq6huqtTSqmKvYuZscqzGAACyQoNuAO4Ujilxr5OoAmFvwmsnq+sY6ujmBuVZb+oZGNlgjnW1mkOoBmJZXyfeOtnr2+geHEUY1xk6nbU7FokA)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://catchts.com/api) helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake in your approach is

```
 type UserInfo = {name:string, last_name:string}

 type user<T> = {
  // you cannot use type T as a key which needs to be a value
  //(that value can be either string or number as key)
   T: UserInfo     //this is incorrect
} 
 type users = {
   users: user<string>
 }
```

Having mentioned that, you can use in-built "Record" type for your goal.

```
type UserInfo = {
  name: string;
  last_name: string;
};

type Users = Record<string, UserInfo>;

// this will suffice, if you want the key to be just string and need not follow any pattern like if its just username or username1.

const users: Users = {
  username: { name: "asdsa", last_name: "asdsa" },
  anyNameOfTheUser: { name: "asdsa", last_name: "asdsadd" },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easy way will by typed as Record like:

```
type UserInfo = {name:string, last_name:string}

 type users = {
   Record<string,UserInfo>
 }
```